# EditorFor with Nullable<long> will trim fractions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following model class inside my asp.net mvc web application :-

```
[Display(Name="RAM (in GB)")]
        public Nullable<long> TOTALMEMORY { get; set; }
```

which represents total memery in bytes. now i need to convert bytes to GB , by doing the following on my controller class :-

```
.MemoryInfo.TOTALMEMORY = (server.SystemInfo.MemoryInfo.TOTALMEMORY / (1024 * 1024 * 1024));
```

Then on the view the will display using the following two syntax as follow:-

```
@Html.EditorFor(model =>model.SystemInfo.MemoryInfo.VIRTUALMEMORY)
```

OR

```
@(Model.SystemInfo.MemoryInfo == null ? "" : Model.SystemInfo.MemoryInfo.TOTALMEMORY.ToString())
```

so in both way if the value in the DB is `8583778304` it will be displayed as `7` instead of `7.99` on the razor view ? can anyone adivce what is the problem ?

**EDIT**
currently the

```
@Html.EditorFor(model =>model.SystemInfo.MemoryInfo.TotalMemoryGB)
```

will display `7.99426651000977` instead of `7.99`

while `@(Model.SystemInfo.MemoryInfo == null ? "" : Model.SystemInfo.MemoryInfo.TotalMemoryGB.ToString())` will display 6.51925802230835E-09 . so can you advice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TOTALMEMORY` is a long value, which means it is an 64-bit integer. It simply cannot house a decimal number like 7.99. And since you use integer division, it will always just trim the result, i.e. ignore everything after the decimal point.

If the decimals are important to you, change it to a nullable double

```
public double? TOTALMEMORY { get; set; }
```

or even better, leave the field as is, to keep the EF mappings, and add a calculated property that connects to it:

```
public long? TOTALMEMORY { get; set; }

[Display(Name="RAM (in GB)")]
public double? TotalMemoryGB 
{
   get 
   {
       // The 1024.0 serves to force double division, instead of integer
       return TOTALMEMORY / 1024.0 / 1024.0 / 1024.0;
   }
   set 
   {
       TOTALMEMORY = (long) (value * 1024 * 1024 * 1024);
   } 
}
```

Now, in your UI you can use TotalMemoryGB exlusively, and work in gigabytes, while preserving the bytes in the database.

Comment: but inside the database the type is biginit which store 8583778304, now when i use Entity framework to map the databse it assign the totalmemeory a tye of long? .

Comment: so if i chnage the type i will get error on the mapping. so is there a way to do the conversion on the view level ?

Comment: @JohnG - it is because you are dividing down to get Gb.  You may want to consider creating a new property on your view model (as you shouldn't be passing domain/entity models directly to your view) as something like `public double? TotalMemoryInGb {get;set;}`

Comment: thanks for the edit, it is partially working , can you check my edit with the issue i currently have ?

Comment: @johnG, you should use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload of the `ToString` method, to specify the display format. In your case, I think `.ToString("F2")` should do the trick.

Comment: i try writting something such as on my view Model.SystemInfo.MemoryInfo.TotalMemoryGB.ToString("F2")), but it did not accept the syntax?